# C++11 string capacity and initialize

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In the following code:

```
string str = "abc";
str.reserve(20);

str.at(10) = 'd'; //LINE1
str[10] = 'd';    //LINE2
```

Both LINE1 and LINE2 will fail because although `str` has capacity of 20, but the index at 10 has not been initialized yet. In this kind of situation, how to initialize the the rest of the capacity? `push_back()` will work, but I have to keep calling `push_back()` until the index 10 location is initialized.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`basic_string::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize).

```
string str = "abc";
str.resize(11);      // will append 8 value (zero) initialized chars
// or
str.resize(11, ' '); // appends 8 ' ' (spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need [`str.append(10, ' ');`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append). Replace ' ' with any character you wish to use to fill the beginning of the string.

Comment: Or you could use `resize`.

Comment: Basically I cannot initialize in the middle. If I want to put chars in to the string str reversely, i.e., from index 19 to index 3, I have to use append(17, ' ') first.

Comment: You will get 'std::out_of_range' exception on `str.at(10) = 'd';` if requested index resides out of current string size. So you have to make the string at least 11 character wide. This could be done with `.resize()` or `append()`

Comment: If you take a look on basic_string implementation, you'll notice that in this particular case there's almost no difference (in actions, in performance etc) which method of the two is to choose. In GCC (GNU STL) `resize()` is implemented via append, if old size of the string is less than new.